# Turn numpy list into column vector

Tags: python, numpy

I can't turn a numpy array into a vector. What I want to do is transform this:

```
>> x.shape
(784,)
```

into this:

```
>> x.shape
(784,1)
```

x was created in the normal numpy.array() way.

Note: I want to change, not create a new array.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a new axis to a vector in multiple ways: e.g. using [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
x = np.zeros(784)
x0 = x.reshape(784, 1)  # shape: (784, 1)
```

or using [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) while slicing:

```
x = np.zeros(784)
x0 = x[:,None]  # short-hand for x[:,np.newaxis], shape: (784, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick

Answer (score 0):

---

Vectors, arrays and lists are totally different data structures, especially in Python. In your question you mentioned `I can't turn a numpy array into a vector`. Actually what you are trying to do is exactly the opposite, means you want to turn a vector of shape (784,) to an array of shape(784, 1). Anyways @cheersmate gave you the correct answer.